# Empty test-unit failure messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

- Ruby version: 1.9.3-p194
- Rails version: 3.2.5

I am having a problem if I use any version of test-unit after 2.4.8.  The problem is that I do not get any meaningful failure messages.  That is, whenever any assertion fails, regardless of reason or type (assert, assert_select, etc.), I get:

```
<> expected but was <>
```

When I switch to test-unit 2.4.8 the messages return to normal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide an minimal working example (MWE)? I tried it with test-unit 2.4.8, 2.4.9 and 2.5.0 - but I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just recreated it by create a new rails app, adding test-unit to the Gemfile, and adding a model using rails g scaffold.  Then in the model's unit test I added assert_equal(2,3) and voila the empty error message fields.  Then I added version 2.4.8 to the test-unit entry in the Gemfile and no more empty error message fields.

Comment: I'm getting this too, any hints, suggestions? if you need someone to help debug, i'm all for it.  it does suck as to why this is happening right?

Comment: Same exact bug on my machine. Looks like it's fixed on the latest development version, which I'm using like this in my Gemfile :

    `gem 'test-unit', :git => "git://github.com/test-unit/test-unit.git"`

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Turns out there was an [issue posted to Github](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/issues/33) related to this. The expected/actual value output seems to have been fixed starting from test-unit version 2.5.1.

Comment: @AndreaSingh - this is an good answer (it solved my problem) - you should move this comment to the answer section so we can give you proper Kudos. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to answer your question directly, as the rubyforge page seems very outdated, but I would strongly recommend that you use the default testing framework that ships with Ruby 1.9.3 (minitest FTW) instead of requiring it explicitly, unless you have a good reason for doing that.

Comment: I am not using minitest because I am using RubyMine < 4 which requires test-unit.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem with the following setup:

- Ruby: 1.9.3-p194
- Rails: 3.2.11
- test-unit: 2.5.0

Updating the test-unit gem to the most recent version (2.5.4) solved the problem for me:

```
bundle update test-unit
```